# Two TextBox one Answer VBA6

Tags: excel, vba

In my UserForm, I have two Text Box. I want to be able to FIND by either Text Box, but use only one or the other. If both are empty I want a MSGBOX telling user to enter information. I can make my code do either/or text box entry but not two textbox where the user skips TextBox1 or does not entry anything. 
Here is my code.....

```
Private Sub OkayCommandButton_Click()
Worksheets("Parts List").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A2").Select
PN = PartNumber.Value
KN = KanbanNumber.Value
If PartNumber = vbNullString Then
   MsgBox "Please enter a Part Number"
   PartNumber.SetFocus
Else
   Cells.find(What:=PN, After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End If
If Kanban = vbNullString Then
   MsgBox "Please enter a Kanban Number"
   PartNumber.SetFocus
Else
   Cells.find(What:=KN, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End If
PartInformation.Caption = _
"Part Number" & vbTab & ActiveCell & vbCrLf & _
"Kanban" & vbTab & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 45) & vbCrLf & _
"Part Name" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf & _
"Supplier" & vbTab & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & vbCrLf & _
"Next Process" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & vbCrLf & _
"Qty in Tote" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 44) & vbCrLf & _
"PC Location" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 46)
PartInformation1.Caption = "Line    " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check first if both TextBox-Elements are empty and then give a message to the user. If that check fails either one or both Text-Box-Elements contain text. You have a conflict there, since you only want to use one TextBox-Element for the search if both textboxes contain a search string. In this case you have to give one of the textboxes priority (the first one you check then wins):

This is only a snippet of your text:

```
PN = PartNumber.Value
KN = KanbanNumber.Value

If ((PartNumber = vbNullString) And (KanbanNumber = vbNullstring)) Then
   ' Both textboxes are empty, message box opened and focus to part number
   MsgBox "Please enter a Part Number or Kanban Number"
   PartNumber.SetFocus
Else
   ' One or more textboxes contain a search string
    If Not (PartNumber = vbNullString) Then
       'Part number is given, run search
       Cells.find(What:=PN, After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Else
       ' Part Number is not given
       ' Since we checked that at least one textbox contains text
       ' the Kanban Number must be set if Part Number has not been set
       Cells.find(What:=KN, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I kept it the way you had it. Since you assign the two variables PN and KN it might be better to check them in the IF-ELSE-statements instead of PartNumber and KanbanNumber directly ...